# Maintain width of Bootstrap "column" element when dragging using jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm facing a problem where we are using the bootstrap (3.x) framework and we've specified that a list of elements is draggable using jquery's `draggable` feature, but as soon as the element begins dragging, it's removed from it's container `.row` flow because jquery adds `position:absolute;` so the proper width is lost.

For instance, if the draggable element had the class `.col-lg-6` it would normally be 50% of the containing `.row` but as soon as I begin dragging, the element instantly becomes 100% of the viewport instead.

How can I style the draggable item so that it maintains its original size during the dragging process?

Comment: Possibly set the width to the exact pixel size on `draggable.create` event?

Comment: can you upload your code?

Comment: @DavidG Thought of that, but I'm trying to maintain as much `vanilla` in the scripts as possible.  Was hoping for a simple method via CSS, but if need be could always fall back on augmenting the `draggable.crate` method.

Comment: @Ashesh I may in a little while, but there's a ton of other junk mixed in so it'd take a while to clean out for this purpose.  The concept is pretty straightforward though, take a column out of a row and it loses it's width, so how can we maintain the width during the drag.

Comment: I don't think there is another way. The `.col-*` classes need to be percentage based as they can be nested. the only alternative you have is to apply your own class in addition to the `.col-*` to fix the width.

Comment: I agree with David to some extent. You could find out the exact width of the element and put it in the code, but then you will loose responsiveness as those elements will (sometimes) fail to adapt on zoom, screen size change , windows re-sizing etc...You may try using the max-width property and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You just need to grab the dimensions from the original element and apply them to the helper element:

```
$(el).draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function (event, ui) {
    var w = $(this).css('width');
    var h = $(this).css('height');
    ui.helper.css('width', w).css('height', h);
  }
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/pix8175/t7fp1bxL/8/)

Comment: The width and height you are getting from the original element are percentage based. Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes I have. Retrieving the width via the jQuery css function always returns the actual width in pixels, including the unit description i.e. '123px'.

Comment: @oucil - added jsfiddle to my answer